# front-pop functionality for JArray

Tags: c#, json.net

Given a (Newtonsoft) JArray object with more than one item contained therein, how can I pop the item off the front and deserialize it? I thought this would work:

```
if (jArray.Count > 0)
    using (var reader = jArray.CreateReader())
            return _serializer.Deserialize(reader, type);
```

but it complains about that array symbol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create an extension method:

```
public static class JsonExtensions
{
    public static T Pop<T>(this JArray jArray)
    {
        T obj = default(T);
        if (jArray.Count > 0)
        {
            obj = jArray[0].ToObject<T>();
            jArray.RemoveAt(0);
        }
        return obj;
    }
}
```

Then you could do:

```
Foo foo = jArray.Pop<Foo>();
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/ChdMhX